# Inserting image in JLabel using HTML in the text property

Tags: java, html, image, swing, jlabel

I want to display an image in a label. But using image icon property I cannot set the size of the image. So I am using HTML coding in the text property of `JLabel` to display image.

The image is not displaying so there must be some error. The alt text is being displayed. I tried the same coding in notepad and it worked. Please mention if there is any other way to display an image of a fixed size in label.

```html
<html>
<body>
<img src="file://C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Wallpapers/New folder/1mb.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="142"  width="142">
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a simple way to resize the image icon then please answer that also. I am making a project for my school so the codings should not be oh high level.
Thank you.

Comment: The size of the imageicon can be changed. What kind of difficult are you facing while trying to change the imageicon size? Please provide sample code.

Comment: I wouldn’t expect this to work, especially if your program is running from a .jar.  Why not just resize the image yourself before creating the ImageIcon?

Comment: `file:` URLs must have a protocol followed by either one slash or three slashes.  Two slashes is wrong—it denotes a [UNC path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Universal_Naming_Convention).

Comment: @VGR while it's entirely possible to load images in HTML in a Java app. (even if the HTML and image is in a Jar), your suggestion *"Why not just resize the image yourself before creating the ImageIcon?"* is the far better idea.